# how to add multiple value to datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Iam trying to do autocomplete input box. Datalist rows are from JSON. I want that user sees name of the city (data[i].stationName below) while making his choise, but i would like to get that data[i].stationShortCode as a return attribute instead of name when city is selected.

Is that possible to do that way without that user needs to see that shortcode?
I tried to put those in array, but iam not figured out how that would help me or..

My js below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url="https://rata.digitraffic.fi/api/v1/metadata/stations";
var stations=[];
var elem;

$.getJSON(url,function(data,status){
    if(status=="success"){
        $.each(data, function(i, item){

            if(data[i].passengerTraffic!=false){
                elem=$("<option value="+data[i].stationName+ ">");
                elem.appendTo('#stations');
                //stations[i]={value: data[i].stationName, data:data[i].stationShortCode};

            } 
            else{

            }

        })

    }
    else{
        console.log("Something went wrong");
    }
})
```

});

And html:

```
<div class="stationSearch">
<input type="text" list="stations" id="station" placeholder="Valitse Asema"/>
<datalist id="stations"></datalist>
    <button class="pick">Paina</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of an array is OK, but it better be an object (or `Map`) so that you have direct access:

```
var stations = {};
// ...

            $("<option>").attr("value", data[i].stationName).appendTo('#stations');
            stations[data[i].stationName] = data[i].stationShortCode;
```

Now when you have the input value in an event handler (e.g. after button click), then get the short code from the input value like this:

```
var selectedShortCode = stations[$("#station").val()];
```

Here is working snippet:

```js
var url="https://rata.digitraffic.fi/api/v1/metadata/stations";
var stations = {};

$.getJSON(url, function(data,status) {
    if (status=="success"){
        $.each(data, function(i, item){
            if(item.passengerTraffic){
                $("<option>").attr("value", item.stationName).appendTo('#stations');
                stations[item.stationName] = item.stationShortCode;
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        console.log("Something went wrong");
    }
});

// ...
$("#station").on("input", function () {
    $("#code").text(stations[$(this).val()]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" list="stations" id="station" placeholder="Valitse Asema"/>
<datalist id="stations">
<option value="shortcode">longcode</option>
</datalist>

Code: <span id="code"></span>
```

Comment: This seems working, but for some reason i get undefined when trying to parse.. Tried this var selectedShortCode = stations[$("#station").val()]. When i logged stations everything seems to be ok: "
Alavus:"ALV"
Aviapolis:"AVP" etc.. What iam missing here..

Comment: What do you mean "when trying to parse"? Make sure you perform the  `stations` lookup only after the Ajax call has returned its response, otherwise it will be empty.

Comment: selectedShortCode = stations[$("#station").val()]; part is not working for some reason.. stations object is ok, and i also get name of the city by $("#station").val(), but i dont get anything out from stations.

Comment: I added a working snippet. You are probably trying to access the `stations` object before the ajax call has returned the result. You should access it in an event handler.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I tried to change stations{} to global and it worked fine.. so obviously i had problem with my calls.. I had previously modified code so that iam calling getStations() (which includes getJSON and was document ready function before) function from click event. Got return {} and list of objects and thought its ok. Now i get it this way: { list of objects} and everything works.. Did not realize that anything was wrong. Iam quite new with js and jquery and these kind of advices helping me a lot with my learning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, modify your script where you build the `<option>` elements as such:

```
if(data[i].passengerTraffic!=false){
    elem=$("<option value=" + data[i].stationShortCode + ">" + data[i].stationName + "</option>");
    elem.appendTo('#stations');
}
```

This will generate `<option>` elements where the "stationShortCode" is the option value and the "stationName" is the displayed value.

Comment: Ahhh, didn't catch that a `<select>` wasn't being used

Comment: I tried this before, and otherwise it was ok, but user sees both values in list and i am trying to avoid that.